# JBoss Server Not Starting From Eclipse and Commandline

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

I started JBoss 7.1 Server from Eclipse without any deployed application and it seems to have stuck at a point. It remains in the Starting state but terminates after the timeout ends. Java version being used here is 1.7. Here are the logs:

```
15:12:18,114 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:12:18,380 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:12:18,439 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
15:12:19,530 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
15:12:19,530 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
15:12:19,542 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
15:12:19,551 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
15:12:19,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
15:12:19,572 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
15:12:19,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
15:12:19,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
15:12:19,620 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
15:12:19,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
15:12:19,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
15:12:19,645 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
15:12:19,648 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
15:12:19,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
15:12:19,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
15:12:19,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
15:12:19,879 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
15:12:19,890 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
15:12:20,413 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
15:12:20,535 WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011600: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
15:12:20,645 WARN  [jacorb.codeset] (MSC service thread 1-3) Warning - unknown codeset (Cp1252) - defaulting to ISO-8859-1
15:12:20,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
15:12:20,736 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=C:\Users\jain\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=C:\Users\jain\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\Users\jain\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\Users\jain\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\messagingpaging)
15:12:20,741 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Waiting to obtain live lock
15:12:20,773 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Using NIO Journal
15:12:20,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
15:12:20,839 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Waiting to obtain live lock
15:12:20,853 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) Live Server Obtained live lock
15:12:20,864 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\jain\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
15:12:20,869 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:4447
15:12:20,871 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
15:12:21,007 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/PIIP]
15:12:21,561 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC service thread 1-1) Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.5.Final-a96d88c 0.0.0.0:5455 for CORE protocol
15:12:21,562 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC service thread 1-1) Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.5.Final-a96d88c 0.0.0.0:5445 for CORE protocol
15:12:21,564 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Server is now live
15:12:21,564 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) HornetQ Server version 2.2.13.Final (HQ_2_2_13_FINAL_AS7, 122) [71fca742-bb48-11e4-b3de-f0fa20524153]) started
15:12:21,567 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) trying to deploy queue jms.topic.testTopic
15:12:21,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/topic/test
15:12:21,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/test
15:12:21,602 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
15:12:21,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
15:12:21,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/RemoteConnectionFactory
15:12:21,605 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.testQueue
15:12:21,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
15:12:21,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/test
15:12:21,614 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test
15:12:21,624 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter] (MSC service thread 1-2) HornetQ resource adaptor started
15:12:21,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
15:12:21,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
15:12:21,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:12:21,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 4129ms - Started 168 of 247 services (78 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Edit:

Although it shows that it has started, but eclipse still shows it in Starting state. After waiting for a long time, it shows the following error, just after those logs:

```
16:40:00,230 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "<machine-name>:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
16:40:08,011 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "<machine-name>:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
16:40:26,588 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "<machine-name>:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
16:40:40,273 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "<machine-name>:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
```

Comment: Log says it's working as per "started in 4129ms". So where it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Which port are you using for accessing JBoss? Try starting JBoss from within Eclipse, open a browser and check http://localhost:8080/ to see if jboss has started. Also check if antivirus software or your firewall is blocking.
refer to https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201728. Maybe this would solve your problem.